# Unable to get value from nested JSON to dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Here is the sample JSON

[image]

Right now I am able to get Bank `HooMan` using `var b = details.b.Select(x => x.Bank).FirstOrDefault();` if I put a breakpoint from the controller. My problem is how would I be able to select Hooman for `@Html.DropDownListFor`

What I tried is this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankID, new SelectList(ViewBag.BankList, "BankID", "BankName", Model.b.Select(x => x.Bank).FirstOrDefault()), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But it doesn't seem to select **HooMan**.. I also tried using `SelectList` on model, like this

```
details.BankList = new SelectList(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BankLists>>(await OperationServices.GetBankListAsync()),
                                        "BankID", "BankName", details.b.Select(x => x.Bank).FirstOrDefault());
//View
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankID, Model.BankList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I have the same result. Dropdownlist was unable to select the data. Anything I am missing? I also need to get values inside `acs`.

EDIT (as requested by Tomato32):

`BankList` is also JSON the we deserialize it to a model. I can get the list and added to a dropdown, but I am not able to select the value from the nested JSON above.

[image]

Comment: Could you post your query to get BankList data, my friend?

Comment: @Tomato32 I updated my question, bankList is also JSON generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend, sorry for the late response.
You selected BankName for Dropdownlist so it can not select true value.

You can set selected the value by JQuery so you don't need to change much code.
Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

1) In controller

```
var selectedBank = bankData.b.Select(t => t.Bank).FirstOrDefault();  //Get the selected bank name

ViewBag.SelectedBankID = banklist.FirstOrDefault(t => t.BankName == selectedBank).BankID; //Get the BankID
```

2) In View

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#BankID').val('@ViewBag.SelectedBankID');

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This should also answer my question although I already thought of one yesterday. We had the same idea, different approach. I just set the value to another property inside the same model and used that data.

Comment: @AdorableVB: Well played, my friend :D